# Redis::CommandError: ERR invalid DB index when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis

I just started working on an existing Rails codebase and I'm trying to run the tests in the codebase. However, when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/` I get the following error on every test:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
Redis::CommandError:
   ERR invalid DB index
 # ./lib/redised.rb:35:in `flushdb_all'
 # ./lib/redised.rb:35:in `each_value'
 # ./lib/redised.rb:35:in `flushdb_all'
```

I'm pretty new to rails -- I've only finished 8 of the 11 chapters in Michael Hartl's rails tutorial -- so I'm not familiar with Redis. My Redis version is `redis-2.4.17`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to increase the number of databases. To do so, I went to `/usr/local/etc` and modified `redis.conf`. I set the database number to 128: `databases 128`.

Comment: I'm currently encountering this issue. Just wondering what your reasoning was for 128 databases.

Comment: @BenMorganIO Its just an arbitrary number above how many my company is using. Its been over a year since I solved this, so I'm not sure; a colleague may have recommended that number to me.

Comment: For some this may be a band-aid rather than fixing the issue of why the index is growing unexpectedly.

Comment: @aceofspades The common case people run into is that their application is configured to use N different Redis databases, but they've configured  their local Redis to run < N. I find it unlikely that the index would "grow unexpectedly"; in most cases the index to use would be hard-coded in a configuration file.

Comment: @MaxGabriel I suspect that there's more to this, especially when running rspec. In fact I believe somewhere the index is hardcoded to 99. Your solution is indeed helpful but I believe increasing config settings to arbitrary values without being sure of the actual reason is less than desirable.

Comment: I had to change the `databases` config in `redis.conf.default` file as it would apparently override the `redis.conf`. The number is not at all arbitrary. Depending on your application's redis configuration, the highest number for your db can not be bigger then what you set in the `redis.conf`.

Comment: For centos, /etc/redis.conf

Answer (score 2):

Though it is too late but may be helpful for others.

If you are using database name like 'test' please replace it something index like '0' / 0. If you are not sure of index try 0 as your index.best of luck